# Cannot get correct href value when crawling sqlite website using BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, html, sqlite, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I tried to get the sqlite download link on the sqlite download webpage using BeautifulSoup.

I can see the correct href value when inspecting the webpage in the chrome.

[screenshot for the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XheGZ.png)

However, I cannot get the href value using python like the code.

```
import urllib.request
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.sqlite.org/download.html"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
link_tags = parsed_html.find_all('a')
pattern = "sqlite-autoconf-(\d+).tar.gz"
pattern_regex = re.compile(pattern)
download_link_tag = next(a for a in link_tags if pattern_regex.match(a.text))
print(download_link_tag.get('href'))
```

Result is

```
hp1.html
```

May I know how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: As [that page explains](https://sqlite.org/hp1.html), you need a browser with JavaScript to get the download link

Comment: Exactly.  Go fetch that page and do "View Source".  The href for all of those tags DOES read "hp1.html".

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. I just notice the information on the `hp1.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sqlite website has HTML that defines the href for that tag as "hp1.html".  That's why you are seeing that as the result.  Once the page loads there is some javascript that replaces the href values for a number of different tags by locating the tags by id and then replacing the href.

What you could do is first find the tag you are looking for, the way you are, and then get that tag's id.  Once you have the tag's id use a regex to search for what href that id should get.

```
import urllib.request
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.sqlite.org/download.html"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
link_tags = parsed_html.find_all('a')
pattern = "sqlite-autoconf-(\d+).tar.gz"
pattern_regex = re.compile(pattern)
download_link_tag = next(a for a in link_tags if 
pattern_regex.match(a.text))

# get the id of the tag where the href you want will go
tag_id = download_link_tag.get('id')

# This pattern will find the href that will replace the current href for a given tag_id
replace_pattern = re.compile(f"'{tag_id}','([^']*)'")

# Now we use our pattern to find all instances where our href is replaced with a new one
print(replace_pattern.findall(str(parsed_html)))
```

This will print:

```
['2022/sqlite-autoconf-3390200.tar.gz']
```

Comment: Genius! Thanks for your answer! I cannot vote the answer because `Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.` but I have accepted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do it like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = "https://www.sqlite.org/download.html"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
dl_url = soup.select('script')[-1].text.split('d391')[-1].split("');")[0].split(",'")[1]
print('https://www.sqlite.org/' + dl_url)
```

This will return:

```
https://www.sqlite.org/2022/sqlite-autoconf-3390200.tar.gz
```

You can use url id's to experiment with getting various links & their names/descriptions, if you want, and then split that script tag's content accordingly. BeautifulSoup docs can be found at https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Sorry, I've accepted another answer since that one is clearer on getting the url. But thanks for your help as well!